# Button is disabled when binding

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a IMvxAsyncCommand method in my ViewModel to perform a server call and depending the result navigate to a ViewModel or other. I don't know why but it is disabling the button where the click event is bind.

```
public IMvxAsyncCommand Register
{
    var runner = Task.Run(() => _service.Register());
    runner.Wait();
    if (runner.Result.Status == SUCCESS)
    {
        return new MvxAsyncCommand(() => _navigationService.Navigate<NextViewModel>());
    }
    else
    {
        return new MvxAsyncCommand(() => _navigationService.Navigate<ErrorViewModel>());
    }
}
```

I tried moving the runner into an async method and set a global variable with the response but I continue to experience this issue. If I comment the service call and leave just the navigationService code then the button is enabled so I guess the problem is the way I am making the service call into this method.

Comment: Calling wait does not make anything async...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code snippet does not compile. If it were a Property Getter, it would block until `_service.Register()` completes, which is probably not what you want. Instead you should put that call into the command and await it:

```cs
private IMvxAsyncCommand _register;
public ICommand Register => _register = _register ?? new MvxAsyncCommand(DoRegisterCommand);
private async Task DoRegisterCommand()
{
    var result = await _service.Register();
    if (result.Status == SUCCESS)
        await _navigationService.Navigate<NextViewModel>();
    else
        await _navigationService.Navigate<ErrorViewModel>();
}
```